# Node.js and Oracle DB: Insert statement doesn't work

Tags: node.js, oracle, sql-insert, node-oracledb

I have a problem according to SQL query. My insert query returns answer that tuple is inserted successfully but actually there is no tuple in table. So for some reasons it doesn't work. 
Query:

```
connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO "+table+
                " VALUES "+
                "(:0, :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11)",
                [objIns.attr1, objIns.attr2, objIns.attr3, objIns.attr4, objIns.attr5, objIns.attr6, objIns.attr7, objIns.attr8, objIns.attr9, objIns.attr10, objIns.attr11, objIns.attr12],
                function(err, result){
                    if (err) {
                        console.error("insert2",err.message); 
                        callback(err.message)
                    } else{
                    console.log("Rows inserted " + result.rowsAffected);
                    }
                });
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE_SOLUTION1: add to your server script: oracledb.autoCommit = true; **

**UPDATE_SOLUTION2: add  { autoCommit: true } to execute() **

Comment: Generally, setting autocommit is a bad practice.  I would add a commit; to your statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If data isn't visible, it is because it wasn't committed.  There are several ways to do this.

If you know an INSERT statement should be committed immediately, the most efficient way is to add the [`execute()` option](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#executeoptions) `autoCommit` like:

```
const r = await connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO "+table+
                " VALUES "+
                "(:0, :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11)",
                [objIns.attr1, objIns.attr2, objIns.attr3, objIns.attr4, objIns.attr5, objIns.attr6, objIns.attr7, objIns.attr8, objIns.attr9, objIns.attr10, objIns.attr11, objIns.attr12],
                { autoCommit: true });
```

A common recommendation for a sequence of INSERTS is to use `autoCommit` only on the last statement.

The equivalent global [`oracledb.autoCommit = true`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbisautocommit) can result in over-committing, which is a waste of resources and may mean that you can't rollback to the desired data state if some part of your application fails.

If you don't want to immediately commit after an `execute()` or `executeMany()`, then you can use an explicit [`commit()`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#commit) at any desired time later.  Note that this requires a 'roundtrip' to the database server unlike the `autoCommit` option which is 'piggybacked' onto the `execute()` or `executeMany()` calls.  Unnecessary roundtrips reduce ultimate scalability.

See the documentation [Transaction Management](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#transactionmgt).

If you are inserting or updating a number of records, it is more efficient to use [`executeMany()`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#batchexecution), which can greatly improve the performance of a series of INSERTs or UPDATEs.

Comment: Christopher Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how node.js works, but Oracle need a commit after an insert, usually.